# Is it possible to internally use HSTS preloading for internal domains?

Tags: hsts

Many companies have internal applications, and it would not be wise to recommend these are opened to the public internet merely for the purpose of them making it onto [the HSTS preload list](https://hstspreload.org/). Even if these services were audited and user credentials are all strong, exposing infrastructure majorly increases the attack surface.

Is there a way to add custom (internal) domains to the preload list in major browsers? For example, rolling this out via the Active Directory to all users?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a good answer, but for future visitors, workarounds can include:

- Setting up a public web server that obtains a valid certificate for the internal domain being used and allows the domain to be added to the preload list. Internal applications should all use subdomains of this domain.
- Rolling out bookmarks that use https:// for the internal applications. This is only about the first request anyway: after that, the browser will have seen the HSTS header from the service itself. This will, however, not redirect any `<a href=http://...>` links upon first visit. I also don't know how often people type an actual domain, especially upon initial discovery, versus clicking a link. This needs to be maintained actively.
- Rolling out a policy that blocks `http://` URLs for each internal application. This has the downside that users see an error page rather than being permanently redirected. The list also needs to be maintained actively.